# Is it possible to use @XmlInverseReference where object and property are of same type?

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling, eclipselink, moxy

I'm using the MOXy JAXB implementation and make quite extensive use of the @XmlInverseReference annotation. However, I've recently encountered a scenario where this approach doesn't seem to work. If I have a class containing a field with a property that's the same type as the parent class, applying @XmlInverseReference seems to suppress the marshalling of that property altogether. Omitting the annotation yields a predictable StackoverflowException.

Has anybody encountered this problem and discovered an effective solution with MOXy?

A quick sample of the offending class:

```
public class Person {

  private Long id;
  private Person spouse;

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  @XmlInverseReference(mappedBy="spouse")
  public Person getSpouse() {
    return spouse;
  }

  public Person setSpouse(Person spouse) {
    this.spouse = spouse;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**EclipseLink MOXy**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)'s `@XmlInverseReference` can be used when the object and property are of the same type.  The current problem with this use case is that the same property needs to be used for both directions of the relationship.

**What Your Seeing**

When a property is annotated with `@XmlInverseReference`, for marshalling MOXy will treat that property as being `@XmlTransient`.

**Enhancement Request**

I have entered the following enhancement request to support this type of behaviour.  Please add any additional details that you feel are relevant.

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/361296

**For More Information on `@XmlInverseReference`**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/jpa-entities-to-xml-bidirectional.html

Comment: Yes, the title in your bug report is a more accurate way of stating the problem. One solution that works for in my use case is annotating the id field with &amp;XmlID and the spouse field with &amp;XmlIDREF. That approach has its limitations,  but manages to sidestep the issue in this particular case.

Comment: @Filip - Using `@XmlID`/`@XmlIDREF` is an approach that you can use.  We'll see what we can do with your enhancement request.  For more info on `@XmlID`/`@XmlIDREF` see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-shared-references-xmlid-and.html